# Regex pattern in Word 2013

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, word-2013

I have a word document which contains 6 series of numbers (plain text, not numbered style) as following:

```
1) blah blah blah
2) again blah blah blah
.
.
.
20) something
```

And this pattern has been repeated six times. How can I used Regex and serialise all numbers before parentheses so that they start with `1` and end up with `120`?

Comment: I think that you can change the numbering settings so that they continue rather than start from the beginning every time. Regular expressions have no concept of numerical addition.

Comment: @npinti I mentioned they are not `numbered` style. They are plain text.

Comment: Word does not have a regex support, only some limited patterns can be used. A macro could be of help here, perhaps. Let's add a VBA tag.

Comment: Are there any lines of text amongst those which *do not* have numbers before them and which should be skipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBA - add this to the ThisDocument module:

```
Public Sub FixNumbers()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim i As Long
    Dim realCount As Long
    realCount = 1
    Set p = Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.First

    'Iterate through paragraphs with Paragraph.Next - using For Each doesn't work and I wouldn't trust indexing since we're making changes
    Do While Not p Is Nothing
        digitCount = 0
        For i = 1 To Len(p.Range.Text)
            'Keep track of how many characters are in the number
            If IsNumeric(Mid(p.Range.Text, i, 1)) Then
                digitCount = digitCount + 1
            Else
                'We check the first non-number character we find to see if it is the list delimiter ")" and we make sure that there were some digits before it
                If Mid(p.Range.Text, i, 1) = ")" And digitCount > 0 Then
                    'If so, we get rid of the original number and put the correct one
                    p.Range.Text = realCount & Right(p.Range.Text, Len(p.Range.Text) - digitCount) 'It's important to note that a side effect of assigning the text is that p is set to p.Next

                    'realCount holds the current "real" line number - everytime we assign a line, we increment it
                    realCount = realCount + 1
                    Exit For
                Else

                    'If not, we skip the line assuming it's not part of the list numbering
                    Set p = p.Next
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can run it by clicking anywhere inside of the code and clicking the "play" button in the VBA IDE.